# css header blinking cursor

Tags: html, css, css-animations

New to JS, HTML, and CSS I was trying out a blinking cursor animation but, I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using Visual Studio the extension "Live Server".  Any assistance or suggestions moving forward is greatly appreciated.

*note I did see several cursor animation questions with answers but none that were similar to the way this one was written so I wanted to try to find a resolution to this one. Using an indefinite loop with a transparent fade.*

saved as index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Sample header</h1>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

saved as index.css

```css
header h1{
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-right: 4px solid #d11313; /*Bliinking cursor*/
}
animation: cursor 1s infinite step-end; /*1sec interval indefinite loop */
@keyframes cursor {
    0%, 100%{border-color: transparent;} /*start is transparent*/
    50%{border-color: #000;} /*50% changes to black&returns to being transparent at 100%*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `animation` CSS property should be inside your `header h1` selector, example below:

```css
header h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-right: 4px solid #d11313; /*Bliinking cursor*/
  animation: cursor 1s infinite step-end; /*1sec interval indefinite loop */
}
@keyframes cursor {
  0%,
  100% {
    border-color: transparent;
  } /*start is transparent*/
  50% {
    border-color: #000;
  } /*50% changes to black&returns to being transparent at 100%*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Sample header</h1>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```